# Why is the winforms designer ignoring attributes on overriden properties?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms, inheritance, attributes

I've got a user control defined like this :

```
  public partial class FooControl : UserControl
  {
      private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox1;
      ...
```

I wanted to make groupBox1.Text accessible directly from the designer so I went for the obvious solution and created the following property in my FooControl :

```
        [CategoryAttribute("Appearance"), DescriptionAttribute("The text associated with this control.")]
        public string Text
        {
            get { return groupBox1.Text; }
            set { groupBox1.Text = value;}
        }
```

This doesn't work because Text is already defined in my super class (in fact, it's a bit in the dark because of the browseable=false attribute, but I eventually found it) :

```
  public class UserControl : ContainerControl
    {

        [Bindable(false)]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        [Browsable(false)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public override string Text { get; set; }
```

An easy workaround is to use "Text2" instead of "Text" as the property name, and in this case everything works fine.

However, if I use override or new, my code compile (and works) but my Text property is not visible in the designer.

What's the reason for this behavior ? Is there a workaround (other than using another property name) ?

Answer (score 1):

I know that is is a very old question and you may have solved this already, but I have found that this works and I wanted to post it for anyone who could benefit:

```
public partial class FooControl : UserControl
{
    string m_text;

    [CategoryAttribute("Appearance"), DescriptionAttribute("The text associated with this control.")]
    [Bindable(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public override string Text
    {
        get { return m_text; }
        set
        {
            m_text = value;
            groupBox1.Text = m_text;
        }
    }

    public FooControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Note, I have not tested the above code in Visual Studio 2008, but it should work without issue.